# Error handling in react-query mutateAsync

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-query

I am learning `react-query` and I want to use the `mutateAsync` in the `useMutation` API. Here is my code:

```
import { useMutation } from "react-query";

const asyncCall = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
    setTimeout(() => reject("reject"), 1000)
  );
};

const Home = () => {
  const { mutateAsync } = useMutation(asyncCall);

  const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
      const res = await mutateAsync();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("catch error"); // output: catch error
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => handleClick()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

Now my code can successfully catches the error returns from the `asyncCall`, but I see a warning in my console:

[image]

details:

[image]

So it says the error comes from the `handleClick` function, but I thought the `try...catch` already taken care of the error? Why there is a warning? How can I fix it?

I made a demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-satoshi-1vbj6?file=/src/Home.js).

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

per default, react-query logs all errors to the console. If you don’t want that, you can override `setLogger`: https://react-query.tanstack.com/reference/setLogger

```
import { setLogger } from 'react-query'

setLogger({
  log: console.log,
  warn: console.warn,
  error: () => {}, // do nothing
})
```